# Draw checkbox tick according to the box size?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls, gdi+

### Introduction

I'm writting a simple checkbox user-control that will draw a background and a tick in a custom color.

To draw the tick, I do this:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Draws the checkbox tick.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="g">The drawing surface.</param>
    ''' <param name="rect">The box rectangle.</param>
    ''' <param name="checkState">The checkbox state.</param>
    Private Sub DrawTick(ByVal g As Graphics,
                         ByVal rect As Rectangle,
                         ByVal checkState As CheckState)

        Select Case checkState

            Case checkState.Checked

                Dim points As PointF() =
                    New PointF() {
                        New PointF(rect.X + 3, rect.Y + 5),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 5, rect.Y + 7),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 9, rect.Y + 3),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 9, rect.Y + 4),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 5, rect.Y + 8),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 3, rect.Y + 6),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 3, rect.Y + 7),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 5, rect.Y + 9),
                        New PointF(rect.X + 9, rect.Y + 5)
                    }

                Using checkPen As New Pen(Me.TickColor, 1)
                    g.DrawLines(checkPen, points)
                End Using

            Case checkState.Indeterminate

                Using checkBrush As New SolidBrush(Me.TickColor)

                    g.FillRectangle(checkBrush, New Rectangle(rect.X + 3,
                                                              rect.Y + 3,
                                                              rect.Width - 5,
                                                              rect.Height - 5))
                End Using

            Case checkState.Unchecked
                ' Do Nothing.

        End Select

    End Sub
```

This is the result:

[image]

---

### Problem

The problem is that the size/points of the tick are specified according to the default checkbox size, I get the main idea from this article:

**[True Transparency support for the .NET CheckBox control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8378/True-Transparency-support-for-the-NET-CheckBox-con)**

So, lets say I increase the box of the checkbox (the width and height of the `rect` var of the code above) then it will draw a tiny tick like this:

[image]

---

### Question

How I could dynamically modify the arithmetic that I do with the Points in the `DrawTick` method to fix the tick size for other box sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a scale factor to determine how much to increase each "x" and "y" coordinate by.  Here's an example (assuming the default checkbox width is 12 pixels, which is just a guess):

```
    Dim scaleFactor As Single = CType(rect.Width, Single) / 12.0
    Dim points As PointF() =
        New PointF() {
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 3, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 5),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 5, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 7),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 9, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 3),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 9, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 4),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 5, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 8),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 3, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 6),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 3, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 7),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 5, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 9),
            New PointF(rect.X + scaleFactor * 9, rect.Y + scaleFactor * 5)
        }
```